# Cannot install any packages

Tags: software-installation

Whenever I try to install any new package, for instance:

```
    sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor
```

I get the same error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-system-monitor is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wvdial:i386 : Depends: libuniconf4.6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I tried instead `apt-get -f install`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
libuniconf4.6:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed: libuniconf4.6:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 68 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/133 kB of archives.
After this operation, 439 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 240834 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libuniconf4.6_4.6.1-7_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libuniconf4.6 (4.6.1-7) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libuniconf4.6_4.6.1-7_i386.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite /etc/uniconf.conf, which is also in package libuniconf4.4 4.4.1-0.2ubuntu2
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libuniconf4.6_4.6.1-7_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also:

- I removed /etc/uniconf.conf and /var/cache/apt/archives/libuniconf4.6_4.6.1-7_i386.deb files manually
- I ran `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get clean`

But nothing solved the problem, what else can I do?

Comment: You may want to check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Can you improve the formatting on this post? I can't tell what's a command and what's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this at your own risk

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb
```